# Creating Third Table Using Two Table With Help Of Spark-Sql or PySpark (No Use of Panda(Python))

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I am trying to Create Third Table Using Two Table With Help Of Spark-Sql or PySpark (No Use of Panda(Python))

#### Dataframe One:

```
+---------+---------+------------+-----------+

|  NAME   | NAME_ID |   CLIENT   | CLIENT_ID |

+---------+---------+------------+-----------+

| RISHABH |       1 | SINGH      |         5 |

| RISHABH |       1 | PATHAK     |         3 |

| RISHABH |       1 | KUMAR      |         2 |

| KEDAR   |       2 | PATHAK     |         3 |

| KEDAR   |       2 | JADHAV     |         1 |

| ANKIT   |       3 | SRIVASTAVA |         6 |

| ANKIT   |       3 | KUMAR      |         2 |

| SUMIT   |       4 | SINGH      |         5 |

| SUMIT   |       4 | SHARMA     |         4 |

+---------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

#### Dataframe Two:

```
| NAME      | NAME_ID   | CLIENT        | CLIENT_ID     |

| RISHBAH   | _____     | SRIVASTAVA    | _____         |

| KEDAR     | _____     | KUMAR         | _____         |

| RISHABH   | _____     | SINGH         | _____         |

| KEDAR     | _____     | PATHAK        | _____         |



###Require Dataframe Output:###

+---------+---------+------------+-----------+

| NAME    | NAME_ID | CLIENT     | CLIENT_ID |


| RISHBAH | 1       | SRIVASTAVA | 6         |


| KEDAR   | 2       | KUMAR      | 2         |

| RISHABH | 1       | SINGH      | 5         |


| KEDAR   | 2       | PATHAK     | 3         |
```

Using Spark-Sql or Spark.

Tried With `df1.join(df2,df1.NAME == df2.NAME,"left")`

But I am Not Getting The Output As Required.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following spark-sql approach

```
val df1 = <assuming data loaded>
val df2 = <assuming data loaded>

//createviews on top of dataframe
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("tbl1")
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("tbl2")

//extract the unique names and nameIds from the first df
uniqueNameDF=sparkSession.sql("select distict name,name_Id from tbl1")
//extract the unique client names and clientIds 
uniqueClientDF=sparkSession.sql("select distict client,client_Id from tbl1")

//create Views on these temporary results
uniqueNameDF.createOrReplaceTempView("name")
uniqueClientDF.createOrReplaceTempView("client")

//join the above views with df2 to get the desired result
resultDF=sparkSession.sql("select n.name,n.name_id,c.client,c.client_id from tbl2 join name n on tbl2.name=n.name join client c on tbl2.client=c.client")
```

Comment: Doesn't Work.
**Query Logic Failed.**

Comment: Can you please tell what issue came up?

Answer (score 0):

```
# FROM DATAFRAME ONE AS df_with_key
# SPLIT OUT DISTINCT BY NAME AND CLIENT
    nameDF=df_with_key.select("NAME","NAME_ID").distinct()
    clientDF=df_with_key.select("CLIENT","CLIENT_ID").distinct()
# DATAFRAME TWO AS df_with_client
    +-------+-------+----------+---------+   
    |   NAME|NAME_ID|    CLIENT|CLIENT_ID|
    +-------+-------+----------+---------+
    |  KEDAR|   null|     KUMAR|     null|  
    |  KEDAR|   null|    PATHAK|     null|   
    |RISHABH|   null|     SINGH|     null|    
    |RISHBAH|   null|SRIVASTAVA|     null|   
    +-------+-------+----------+---------+
# NOW JOIN FIRST WITH NAME AND THEN CLIENT
    df_with_client.drop("NAME_ID").join(nameDF,nameDF.NAME==df_with_client.NAME,"LEFT").drop(nameDF.NAME).drop("CLIENT_ID").join(clientDF,df_with_client.CLIENT==clientDF.CLIENT).drop(clientDF.CLIENT).select("NAME","NAME_ID","CLIENT","CLIENT_ID").show()

    +-------+-------+----------+---------+
    |   NAME|NAME_ID|    CLIENT|CLIENT_ID|
    +-------+-------+----------+---------+
    |  KEDAR|      2|     KUMAR|        2|
    |  KEDAR|      2|    PATHAK|        3|
    |RISHABH|      1|     SINGH|        5|
    |RISHBAH|      1|SRIVASTAVA|        6|
    +-------+-------+----------+---------+
```